# How can I remotely manage Outlook profiles on client machines?

Tags: exchange, outlook

I would love to be able to remotely add/remove mailboxes or PSTs without starting a remote assistance session. Is there a way to script these actions or an easy way to make this work remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I both run a hosted Exchange environment and resell for another, and there's nothing I've ever found that does that remotely.  We do a lot of remote sessions because of that...

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that this is possible. I haven’t seen any 3rd party tools to be able to do this. You need to edit the user’s profile. With a little time you could probably find out what registry keys are used and use "Remote Registry" and edit it manually. But it would be quicker to just connect each time.